# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on android input form

Tags: java, android

I have an input form that has 38 fields
I know it's too much but my boss want it to be like that

There are 4 edit texts and spinners as the rest and 1 imageView that'll be uploaded to server using http client

I use AsyncTask to send the data like this :

```
new asyncTask().execute(array, array, array);
```

Because there's too many of items, I think I missed one of them
I've checked many times but I still get the `indexOutOfBounds` exception

Can you help me find them or give me solution / advice to make simpler code

Here's the code (your eyes might hurt coz it's the whole code) :

http://pastebin.com/0dUss9ak

(it's too much to write here)

Why i'm using alphabets for the variable's name?
If I use name for each of them i'll be dead.

Thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line

`new KirimData().execute(id_user, nama, lokasi, keterangan, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, ad, bd, cd, dd, ed, fd, gd, hd, id, jd, kd, ld, md, nd, od, pd, qd, savedImagePath);`

You seem to be missing parameter `j`, which will (very probably) cause an exception in

`KirimData#doInBackground`

Answer (score 1):

To make your code and variables easier to manage, I would highly recommend using [`HashMaps`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html) that use the field names (i.e. `a`, `b`, `c`, etc. in your code) as keys:

```
HashMap<String, String> fieldValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, Spinner> fieldSpinners = new HashMap<String, Spinner>();
```

You could drastically reduce your code replication (and the mistakes like this that code replication brings about) by iterating over the keys in your `HashMap` and executing the same same logic during each iteration (as opposed to copying/pasting the same lines of code for each field).

Also, I would recommend using more meaningful field names.  It might not yield as compact code as you have now, but it will be easier to read and maintain in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a malicious code in onCreate:

```
    File nfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Android/data/com.nigmagrid.jm.demo/");
     nfile.mkdir();
```

why you always create directory every time the application start ?

If you want really bad to put that many spinner, 
I suggest you should add your spinner on the way which add it programmatically.
- First you may inflating your main layout

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup inflatedLayout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(<your layout xml>, null);
```

Then put the Spinner content on ArrayAdapter

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.add("Jembatan 1");
    adapter.add("Jembatan 2");
    adapter.add("Jembatan 3");
```

I don't know if every Spinner have a different content.
if they did, you may declare different adapter or create it from a resource.
Then add all spinner that you want:

```
    for(int i=0;i<35;i++){
        Spinner s = new Spinner(this);
        s.setAdapter(adapter);
        s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Spinner s = (Spinner) parent;
                String selectedItem = (String) s.getSelectedItem();
                Toast.makeText(InflateCoba.this, selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // or you can assign it to a variable
                // selectedStr[i] = selectedItem;
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });
        inflatedLayout.addView(s);
    }
```

set as main View

```
    setContentView(inflatedLayout);
```

on btn_proses click listener, I suggest you should not create new Object of asyncTask,
declare it in initialization and use the instance that you declare.

```
    HashMap<String, Object> kirimPaket = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    kirimPaket.put("nama", nama);
    kirimPaket.put("keterangan", keterangan); // and do the rest ..
    kirimPaket.put("spinnerItem", selectedStr);
    kirim.execute(kirimPaket);
```

which kirim is an instance of KirimData.
Use HashMap and put your packet on there, it will make it simple.

```
    protected class KirimData extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, String>
```

Actually I don't like the way asyncTask send parameters, Google should do it simple.
then the finalize it

```
    @Override
        protected String doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... params) {
            try{
                HttpClient httpClient = CustomHttpClient.getHttpClient();
                HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(VarsUrl.getServerAddress()+"simpan-inspeksi-jembatan.php");

                MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                String nama = params[0].get("nama");
                String keterangan = params[0].get("keterangan"); // and do the rest  ..
                String[] selectedStr = params[0].get("spinnerItem");

                reqEntity.addPart("nama", new StringBody(nama));
                reqEntity.addPart("keterangan", new StringBody(keterangan)); // and do the rest  ..
                for(int i=0;i<selectedStr.length;i++){
                    reqEntity.addPart("item_"+i, new StringBody(selectedStr[i]));
                }
           ....
```

Comment: thanks, i'll move that directory mkdir script. At the looping script for the spinner, how to add a TextView below the Spinner?
those spinners has same value they only contain Yes and No

Comment: you should move that mkdir script or your application will be crashed,  spend a lot of space. And about add TextView below them, if you have linearlayout - vertical as your main, just do `inflatedLayout.addView(textView);` after add the spinner. If you have a RelativeLayout, use the [LayoutParam](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) to set TextView position. done